# Using Smarty to define date inside a blog entry

Tags: php, smarty

I want my users to be able to use different date formatting without using the date_format option Smarty comes with, for different reasons.

So i tried following:

Template

```
{foreach from=$list_entries item=row_entries}
 <h1>{$row_entries.title}</h1>
 <p>{$row_entries.content}</p>
{/foreach}
```

PHP

```
$blog_template = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM installed_designs WHERE u_id='$current_user_id' AND standard='1'"));

$smarty = new Smarty();

$result_entries = $con->query("SELECT * FROM entries");
$list_entries=array();
while ($row_entries = $result_entries->fetch_assoc())
{
$list_entries[]=$row_entries;
}


$smarty->assign('TemplateCSS', $blog_template["css"]);

$template_string = $blog_template["template"];
$smarty->assign('list_entries', $list_entries);

// Debugging and caching
$smarty->debugging = false;
$smarty->caching = false;
$smarty->cache_lifetime = 0;
$smarty->display('string:'.$template_string);
```

But the date remains same in every entries. 
Is there a way to work this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep overwriting and assigning the same global variable. Instead, add a new array key with the formatted time:

```
$row_entries["formatted_time"] = date("H:s:i", $row_entries["time"]);
$list_entries[] = $row_entries;
```

You can also just overwrite the existing `time` key if you wish. Then when you loop though `$row_entries` in your template, just output the formatted time without a modifier.

```
{ foreach from=$list_entries item=row }
   Time: { $row->formatted_time }
{ /foreach }
```

You might be interested in making a custom modifier that formats dates a little easier (if you use the same formatting a lot), so you can use something like:

```
{ $myDate | myDateFormat }
```

Comment: By the way, you probably mean `H:i:s`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the H:i:s issue. I'm quite new using Smarty, are you able to put the whole solution together so that i can see exactly what you mean? I tried some variants, but it did not work. And thanks for the suggestions, i'll definitely look into that later.

Comment: Sure, although I though I made it clear as possible. Post your whole code into your question and I can help you.

Comment: Sorry about that. Still young and dumb, but trying. Edited my question anyway, that's what I  have by now.

Comment: I don't see the content of `$template_string` which is where you actually output this data. Have you tried to implement my suggestion? It's just not clear where you're stuck. Forget the custom modifiers for now, that's more advanced. I forget if Smarty syntax is `{$row->formatted_time}` or `{$row.formatted_time}` but try it out.

Comment: It's in a database for now. Added the template in my question.

Comment: Sure, but what seems to be the issue? What can I clarify?

Comment: Thank you, no further questions. It works perfectly now, it was just me messing around too much.